# How to add Chrome to a container to over come the error 'Failed to launch chrome' in circleCI

Tags: puppeteer, circleci, codeceptjs

I'm trying to run Codecept.js on circleCI but I keep running into the same issue where it says `Failed to launch chrome`.

I believe it is a problem with puppeteer but I cannot find the issue online.

I've tried adding the following to my codecept.conf.js file.

```
  helpers: {
    Puppeteer: {
      url: process.env.CODECEPT_URL || 'http://localhost:3030'
    },
    chrome: {
      args: ["--headless", "--no-sandbox"]
    }
  },
```

I've tried to install chrome onto the container that I'm running:
`docker-compose exec aubisque npx codeceptjs run --steps`

As I thought it might be that chrome didn't exist. I couldn't figure out how to do this though. I have also read that puppeteer uses its own type of chrome :S.

```
 acceptance:
    working_directory: ~/aubisque-api
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:latest-browsers
        environment:
          NODE_ENV: development
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - restore_cache:
          name: Restore NPM Cache
          keys:
            - package-lock-cache-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
      - run:
          name: Install git-crypt
          command: |
            curl -L https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt/archive/debian/0.6.0.tar.gz | tar zxv &&
            (cd git-crypt-debian && sudo make && sudo make install)
      - run:
          name: decrypt files
          command: |
            echo $DECRYPT_KEY | base64 -d >> keyfile
            git-crypt unlock keyfile
            rm keyfile
      - run:
          name: Build and run acceptance tests
          command: |
            docker-compose -f docker-compose-ci.yml build --no-cache
            docker-compose -f docker-compose-ci.yml up -d
            docker-compose exec aubisque npx codeceptjs run --steps
```

This is my circle/config.yml file where I run my acceptance tests. I am running the code in workflows and before I run this job I am running a job that installs the npm modules.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: yeah I really do

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with the problem you're having, but in the `codecept.conf.js` file, the `chrome` settings should be **within** the `Puppeteer` block.